# Flashing airbag warning lamp 1995 Mercury Villager

Tags: repair, supplemental-restraint-system

RE: 1995 Mercury Villager GS

The airbag warning lamp continuously flashes at a frequency of "on-off-on-off" once per second. It began flashing after reassembly of steering wheel after a clock-spring replacement and power-steering pump replacement. It appears to just require a reset. OBD1 certified.

SOLVED by a simple diagnostics/reset of the SRS:
1) Open the driver's side door. 2) Put the key in the ignition and turn to On/ACC-only, 3) Within 7 seconds of turning the key to ON/ACC, push the driver's side door-switch button at least 5 times. 4) The Air Bag lamp should go solid...give it at least 7 seconds, and then should begin to blink a 3 second, 1 second on/off pattern. 5) After 30-seconds, turn ignition to OFF and remove key. 6) Start vehicle, and wait for the Air Bag light to turn off to verify that it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!